# React Redux Localization in the Class Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

I am developing a React Application and I added React Redux Localization library from [AlternativaPlatform](https://github.com/AlternativaPlatform/react-redux-localization) for localization and text translation to my application. The library works fine for simple text because I will need to call `<Translate value="hello" />` every time I want to translate the text and this component will return the string within the `<span></span>` tag. I am having trouble to translate all texts which are defined in the class component. I have done a research and read the documentation but I did not find a solution since yesterday.

What I have been trying to do, I created the following files in my project;

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { localeReducer } from 'react-redux-localization';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ locale: localeReducer });
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavigationBar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';

/*
* Home component
*/
export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationBar />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, OverlayTrigger, Popover, InputGroup, Button, FormControl, Tooltip, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { localize } from 'react-redux-localization';
import translations from './translation/data-translations.json';

import Switcher from './translation/Switcher';
import Translate from './translation/Translate';

/*
* Navigation bar Component
*/
class NavigationBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar fixedTop>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <NavLink to="/"><img alt="logo" src="/logo.png" className="cfn-logo" /></NavLink>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <div className="top-navigation">
            <Nav>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="https://twitter.com/code4africa" target="_blank"><Translate value="Get_in_touch" /></NavItem>
              <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="bottom" overlay={<EmbedPopup />} rootClose={true}>
                <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#"><Translate value="Embed_this" /> <i className="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></NavItem>
              </OverlayTrigger>
              <NavItem className="navitem-divider"></NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={3} href=" https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
                <i className="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                <i className="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
            <div className="language-switcher-btns">
              <Switcher />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar >
    );
  }
}

export default localize(translations)(NavigationBar);
```

And the Translate component as;
**./traslation/Translate.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { localize } from 'react-redux-localization';
import translations from './data-translations.json';

const Translate = ({ l , value}) => (
  <span>{l(value)}</span>
);

export default localize(translations)(Translate);
```

By calling the Translate component as `<Translate value="hello" />` it will return the translated value based on the locale **BUT** inside `<span></span>` tag. I tried to remove the `<span></span>` in the Translate component but it does not compile.